# Getting the error "Is not a valid short File Name" when running the installer made by Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

There is an older program written in `VS2010` that I want to recompile and deliver its installer. It is using the setup program that was coming with `VS2010` but I haven't personally used them and don't know much about it.  When I rebuild it, generates two files, one an `MSI` and one a `setup.exe` When I run the `setup.exe` I get this erorr: `'<Company_Name>' is not a vali short file name.`

I did some searching and found this one in `SuperUser`: https://superuser.com/questions/258239/error-1325-username-is-not-a-valid-short-file-name  but I don't think that is the exact issue I am having.

How should I fix this problem? What is causing it?

Comment: Use the .msi file to install the application, not the setup.exe

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the installer was set to install it an `D:\` drive by default but we didn't have a `D:\` drive, changed it to `C:\` and it worked.

Comment: It's also possible to have a D: and not a C:.  Rare but I've seen it.  Installers should be defaulted to [ProgramFilesFolder]Company\Product or [ProgramFiles64Folder]Company\Product not 'X':\

Comment: yeah, looks like the client wanted it to be default to D drive, I don't even know how to work with installer in VS but got lucky and found this one, in the UI they can still change it to D